# Average of a column when some of the values are text and not numbers?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is the table, please write me a DAX function that calculates the average value (do not count the "X"'s or blanks in the calculation).

| Column |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 3 |
| X |
|  |
| X |
| 10 |

The final answer should spit out a value of 5.25.

Please don't give me a vague answer like "just transform your column to all number format in the transformation tab". I've tried that and apparently I'm not doing something right because I still get errors when trying to write my function, it says that powerbi cannot compute the average of a string value.

Below is my current formula I have tried:

```
COLUMN AVERAGE = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(
        FILTER(
            TABLE,
            TABLE[COLUMN] <> "X"
        ),
        FILTER(
            TABLE,
            TABLE[COLUMN] <> ""
        )
    )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are using `AVERAGE(<column>)` without a column reference but 2(!) table references

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `AVERAGE(<column>)` without a column reference but 2(!) table references, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/average-function-dax)

Use this measure instead:

```
Average Column = 
AVERAGEX(
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Column] <> BLANK() 
        && 'Table'[Column] <> "X"),
    VALUE('Table'[Column])
)
```

`AVERAGEX(<table>,<expression>)` iterates over a filtered table (w/o "X" or blanks) and averages the expression `VALUE(<text>)` - which is a number - for all rows.

If you are having trouble reproducing the above measure try the self-containing one below which includes your sample data too.

```
Average Column = 
VAR tbl = 
    DATATABLE(
        "Column", STRING,
        {
            {3}, {5}, {3}, {"X"}, {}, {"X"}, {10}
        }
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(
        FILTER(
            tbl,
            [Column] <> BLANK() 
            && [Column] <> "X"),
        VALUE([Column])
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, doen't work. Same error shows: "MdxScript(Model) (43,5) Calculation error in measure 'TABLE'[COLUMN1]: Cannot convert value " of type Text to type Number."

Comment: That's not possible since it's working for me: FILTER removes X and BLANK(), AVERAGEX iterates over all the remaining rows of the filtered table and VALUE() converts text to number

Comment: I added a self-contained measure to the answer that works whatever your data model looks like.